# NameError at / name 'blog' is not defined

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm using Django 1.5.1. I'm trying to figure this name error out, even though I've include from . import views in my main urls.py

the code is here http://dpaste.org/ooPOU/

Answer (score 4):

your forgot quotes around "blog.urls"

```
  url(r"^blog/", include("blog.urls", namespace="blog"))
```